# Fabric8 Maven Plugin to build docker image

Tags: maven, docker, fabric8

I'm trying to configure Fabric8 Maven plugin to build a docker image for my Spring Boot application.

The following dockerHost configuration works in Ubuntu.

```
<dockerHost>unix:///var/run/docker.sock</dockerHost>
```

However, I'm trying to make it work in Windows 10 but couldn't do so. 
What is the equivalent in Windows 10?

Comment: Which version of fabric8 maven plugin are you using?

Comment: <version>0.20.0</version>

Comment: I think you're talking about [docker-maven-plugin](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin), not fabric8 maven plugin. Could you please share your complete plugin configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed Docker using the Docker toolbox, then you can find the Docker host by running:

```
docker-machine env default
```

Where `default` is the name of the docker machine, which can be found by running `docker-machine ls`.

It is also possible to not specify the dockerHost in the pom file, and use the `DOCKER_HOST` env variable. This variable can be exported using

```
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

Comment: Could you print out an example value please, to help understand the format;
I don't have a local docker, I'm trying to connect to a remote machine....